# How to display data from Google sheet using datatables

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, datatables, spreadsheet

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to build a web app using Google app scripts.
What I'm trying to achieve is to display data from Google sheet to a HTML page using datatables.
But it just seems that the table won't get displayed.

Here is my code

code.gs

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("dt").evaluate();
  //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("datatables").evaluate();
}

function getSpreadsheetData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetid"); //ss = spreadsheet
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("database_edited"); //ws = working sheet
  //const firstCell = ws.getRange("A1");
  //const dataRange = firstCell.getDataRegion();
  const dataRange = ws.getRange("A:F")
  const data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  const headersArray = data.shift();
  const headersObject = headersArray.map(header => {return {title:header}});
  //console.log(data);
  //console.log(headersObject);
  return{data: data, headers: headersObject};
```

dt.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="tes"></h1>
    
    <table id="tabelp" class="display" width="100%"></table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      function dispData(dataSet) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#tabelp').DataTable( {
            data: dataSet.data,
            columns: dataSet.headers
          } );
        } );
      }
       
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dispData).getSpreadsheetData();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Display data from Google sheet to a HTML page using datatables.

Comment: I think that your script works and the values will be shown in the HTML. But, you say `But it just seems that the table won't get displayed.`. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue. Can you provide the detail of `But it just seems that the table won't get displayed.`? For example, does an error occur? And, in your situation, when you redeploy Web Apps by reflecting the latest script, what result will you obtain?

Comment: By the way, in your script, in order to use the data range, I would like to recommend modifying from `const dataRange = ws.getRange("A:F")` to `const dataRange = ws.getRange("A1:F" + ws.getLastRow())`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion, I don't know why, but now it works. By doesn't work I mean the table isn't displayed, maybe it just takes some time to load. But now it works, and the suggestion's working good too. Thanks again.

Comment: That first block of code is malformed as you have it.  A copy/paste issue perhaps?